# Difference between translation, align and margin in android

Tags: java, android, alignment, translation, margin

What is the difference between **translation**, **align** and **margin** in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Translation** in x or y of the view. This value is added post-layout to the sides or height property of the view, which is set by its layout.

**Alignment** in Android is used only for text.
Defines the alignment of the text. A heuristic is used to determine the resolved text alignment.

**Margin** Specifies extra space on the left, top, right and bottom sides of this view. This space is outside this view's bounds. Margin values should be positive.

Answer (score -6):

As the tag description says, **translation** is the process of replacing strings in an application or website to make interfacing with the application or website easier for people from countries with different languages.

**Align** it's just positioning of GUI elements.

**Margin** defines space around elements.

Comment: translation as in translating a view in the x or y direction not language translation - good lord!